# undefined method `status' for nil:nilclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Getting this when trying to link together a controller with its index view.

With this in the controller:

```
class FeedbackController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

And this in the routes:

```
resources :feedback
```

I get this:

```
NoMethodError in FeedbackController#index

undefined method `status' for nil:NilClass
```

And this stack trace:

```
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
omniauth (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:177:in `call!'
omniauth (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:157:in `call'
omniauth (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:177:in `call!'
omniauth (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:157:in `call'
/Users/macbook/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rack-facebook-signed-request-802e6f0820f1/lib/rack/facebook/signed_request.rb:32:in `call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:339:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2909243921452486150__call__401413506945164242__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `catch'
thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
eventmachine (1.0.0) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
eventmachine (1.0.0) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:86:in `start'
thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
thin (1.5.0) bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/macbook/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `load'
/Users/macbook/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
```

I've tried pluralizing the controller to Feedbacks and adjusting the routes/filenames appropriately but I still get that error.

Also tried using `:as => :feedback` but still get the error.  If I don't have the `/feedback/index.html.haml` in the folder it will throw the right Template Missing page, but even with a totally empty model, controller and view it shows this status error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured this one out... what an oddball.

You can't have a response method defined in your controller.  So I had:

```
def response
end
```

And just having that will cause this error!

Comment: (Isn't there a `response` method already, to get the response? So this would make sense.)